# Slice part of value in one column for each row

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I want select digit 5:8 of a 10 digit string number for each row of one column. I have tried indexing in loops but that seems very tedious. Is there a more simple method?

Small example of the data:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [[1, 2, '12345678910'], [1, 2, '10987654321'], [1, 2, '11029384756']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3])
```

*Var3* should be manipulated and the outcome should be strings of shorter length:

```
data = [[1, 2, '5678'], [1, 2, '6543'], [1, 2, '3847']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the apply function to the specific column and then get the substring for each value:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 2, '12345678910'], [1, 2, '10987654321'], [1, 2, '11029384756']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3'])

df['Var3'] = df['Var3'].apply(lambda x: x[4:8])
```

Note: In your result you are not extracting the 5:8 characters, but I hope you get the idea.